# How to set a default date in html?

Tags: html

I am editing a HTML file and there is one attribute application deadline. How can I set a default value to the application deadline to one year after today in the html code? Thanks for helping

Below is the original HTML code

```
    <div class="field" >
        Application Deadline:
        <input type="date" id="id_application_deadline" name="application_deadline">
    </div>>
```

Comment: use Java Script simply HTML won't do the work. HTML is just static representation of the data.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without java script, Try this

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
today = new Date();
document.write("", today.getDate(),"/",today.getMonth()+1,"/",today.getYear());
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the desired date as value attribute:

```
<input type="date" id="id_application_deadline" name="application_deadline" value="2013-05-29">
```

If you're only using html, without javascript, there won't be a way to calculate the 1 year offset i think.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onload()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  yyyy = parseInt(yyyy) + 1;
  today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
  document.getElementById("id_application_deadline").value = today;
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="onload()">

    <div class="field" >
        Application Deadline:
        <input type="text" id="id_application_deadline" name="application_deadline">
    </div>

</body>
```